# SELECT(MAX) not going past 10 - mysql with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin, max

I'm creating a PHP script to insert rows into a database called orders based on a shopping cart that is stored in an associative array using a sessional array $_SESSION['cart']. The database looks something like this:

```
orders
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
   Id     |   Username   |   Item1Id   |   Item2Id   |   Item3Id   |
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
1         | a@aa.com     |   8000001   |   8000002   |   800003    |
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
5         | a@aa.com     |   7000001   |   6000002   |   700003    |
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
7         | b@bb.com     |   8000001   |   8000002   |    NULL     |
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
10        | a@aa.com     |   3000001   |   1000002   |   800009    |
----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Id column type is CHAR(20) as I may choose to use letters later on.

As part of inserting the row, I need to assign an Id (Primary Key) to the order row which will be set to 1 higher than the current highest Id number found.

The whole script works perfectly; query finds highest Id in the table and I increment that by 1 and assign it to a variable to use as part of the insert query. The only problem is that "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM orders" can't seem to find anything higher than 9. Is there a condition which prevents the SELECT MAX(Id) from identifying anything in double digits?

I've got it written like:

```
$highestID = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM orders");

$orderID = $highestID +1;
```

I've emptied the database except for Id numbers1 and 2. Running the PHP script inserts new rows with Id numbers 3, 4, 5 except when it gets to 10, the script is unable to as it produces an error of having duplicate primary key of '10' (from $orderID's value). Even when manually entering a row into the database with Id of '25', $orderID still only returns '10' when I echo out its result.

I have not set any specific limits to the amount of rows that can be entered or anything like that.

Comment: Use `cast` in query - `select max(cast(Id as unsigned)) from orders`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really do not need to go through ALL that trouble for an auto-incremental PK. Here's how you can go about it.

**Step 1 :** In your phpmyadmin, edit your table, and check the `A_I` checkbox for your PK column.

**Step 2 :** While inserting from PHP, leave the field blank. It will automatically assign a value of the `current max + 1` to your PK.

Eg,

```
$query = "Insert into mytable (id, name) values ('', 'Name1'), ('', 'Name2')";
```

**Edit :** You really cannot have a `CHAR(20)` PK and then expect the increment to work btw.

Comment: This helps a lot but in theory, incrementing my own way through the PHP script should provide the same functionality shouldn't it? Also, how can I be certain the A_I will work for the highest order number that currently exists?

Comment: The extra bit of code that you have to write is still unnecessary. A_I automatically picks up the max value of the integer. Editing my answer to answer your first query.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is `char(20)` so `order by Id` using string sort. You could use `cast` or `convert` function to sort numbers.

Like:
`select max(cast(Id as unsigned)) from orders`